# Is there a way to define the src of an ImageView as an style id

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

I would like to make the image change based on the theme (for Day-Night mode).

I've tried creating an id with the name "logo" in the style.xml that contains the drawable reference for the logo and change it according to the style but I don't know how to set this id as the ImageView source.

In the style.xml:

```xml
<resources>
<item type="drawable" name="logo"></item>
...
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
<item name="logo">@drawable/logo</item>
...
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
<item name="logo">@drawable/logodark</item>
...
</resources>
```

I don't know how I would reference it in the ImageView as the intelisense can't seen to find any "logo" id when I try to write in "app:srcCompat" as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRIej.jpg).

How can I make the ImageView source change based on the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just found out about tints.

The style.xml goes like this

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
...
<!-- This sets the image tint for the style. -->
<item name="android:tint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
...
</style>
```